# Triple fault with higher-half kernel and interrupts

Tags: paging, virtual-memory, interrupt-handling, osdev, fault

I am developing a tiny operating system for learning purposes (code here: https://github.com/davidedellagiustina/ScratchOS).

I have a **higher half kernel** running at `0xc0004000`, mapped to physical `0x4000`. The default page directory maps this area correctly and then has an entry for identity mapping the first 1MB of RAM (needed to jump to higher half). After entering the higher half, I delete the first entry of the page directory, invalidate the TLB and everything is fine (I get page faults if I try to access address `0x4000`, so the page directory is updated successfully).

After that I set up an interrupt vector and interrupt handler functions for time and keyboard, and eventually I try to create a new and more complete page directory and replace the boot one, but I get a triple-fault when replacing the old one.

Currently the only way I can avoid the triple-fault is loading a new page directory that identity maps the first 1MB of RAM, and even trying to delete the first entry of the page directory after loading it (as I did during boot process) results in a triple-fault (so the identity mapping **must** stay there).

I was able to find out that disabling interrupts *before* switching page table (or even never re-enabling them after switching to protected mode, earlier on boot [comment instruction `asm volatile("sti");` in function `irq_init()` at the bottom of file `src/cpu/isr.c` to test]) prevents the CPU from triple-faulting. So, I guess that I may have some problems with either my IDT (files `src/cpu/idt.*` and `src/cpu/isr.*`) or my GDT (loaded back in boot process when switching to protected mode, files `src/boot/bootsect.asm` and `src/boot/gdt.asm`). I aready double checked all the addresses loaded in these two structures. What am I missing? It looks like to me that it triple-faults because at some point, with no identity mapping of the first page, it cannot find the entire interrupt vector (which is loaded in virtual memory inside kernel, so mapped to physical first page), but the strange behaviour is that (see first paragraph) if the page directory which does not identity map the first 1MB is the boot one, it doesn't complain.

Can anybody help find out my mistake(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gdt and idt registers both take virtual addresses.  When you disable the low mapping, that means that the next reference to the gdt or idt will cause a page fault.   You need to reload both of these registers with their high-address equivalent before deleting the unity-page.

Comment: I'll try to look into that, thank you!
The strange fact that I still don't understand is why everything works for the first time I delete the identity mapping and invalidate the TLB...

Comment: By the way, do you mean the registers containing GDT and IDT references (those loaded with lgdt and lidt instructions) or the addresses inside the GDT/IDT structures themselves?

Comment: Yes; but if you did have gate descriptors in either of those tables, they have to point to valid virtual addresses as well.   Conceptually, segments are applied before pages.

Comment: Finally fixed the bug, I'll explain it there. The IDT was fine as it was already loaded from the higher-half, the problem was with the GDT. I just needed to `lgdt [eax]` with the new virtual address in `eax` and change the second entry of the GDT descriptor (i.e. the base address of the GDT structure) with a virtual address too! Now it's working correctly, thanks a lot!
If anyone will have the same problem, see commit `df3637c` in my repository for implementation details.